# Finding out the buffer size of external hdd connected via USB

Tags: external-hdd

I want to securely delete the hdd using dd because I intend to sell it. Using the buffer will speed up the process. I can't find out the size though:

```
arno@arno-X55A:~$ hdparm -i /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: Permission denied
arno@arno-X55A:~$ sudo hdparm -i /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for arno: 

/dev/sdb:
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb1
```

Replace sdb1 with your hard drive name

***it has to be an uppercase `I`**

[image]